# Какой метод использовать чтобы красиво тащить карточку пальцем как в тиндере , и чтобы анимация была такая же?

Tags: java, android, drag-n-drop, swipe

Делаю приложение в android studio на java. Для заучивания иностранного словаря.

У меня приложение языковое, где карточки с переводом листать надо. Сейчас при свайпе уже после самого свайпа карточка улетает в сторону, а я хочу чтобы как в тиндере ее тянешь пальцем, и она тянется за пальцем и улетает 1)либо когда дотянул ее до края и отпустил, 2)либо если достаточно быстро свайпнул (можно не до края) и она улетела. Я сначала думал что это drag and drop, но кажется нет. Буду благодарен, если наставите меня на путь и подскажете где искать решение.

PS хочу ещё чтобы как в тиндере при сдвигании карточки влево на ней загоралась надпись ("выучено"/"заучивать") с яркостью, пропорциональной амплитуде сдвига.

Надеюсь, понятно сформулировал. Заранее спасибо.

(PPS если с тиндером сложный пример, то ещё очень хорошо сделан свайп карточки в приложении reWord - вот мне нужно нечто подобное.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас есть инструменты "Из коробки" типа Drag and Drop. Если вас это не устраивает, то вы пишите свои реализации либо ищете готовые решения в виде библиотек в интернете. Я уверен, что ребята из Тиндера себе писали для этих целей свою реализацию.

Comment: Можете использовать данную библиотеку: https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView